# How can I increase the quality of my VRay render in rhino?

Tags: 3d, render-settings

I have tried rendering an image several times in VRay using the denoiser and setting the render output to very high but I still keep getting a pixilated image. I have run renders before that have been much higher quality and I can’t remember doing anything differently. Any ideas what could be the issue?

The first picture is of my Asset Editor and the settings I used, the second is the resulting render.[image] [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does rendering it at a lower resolution look - the same or worse?

My first inclination would be to double the output resolution (7200 x 4050) and compare that image to this one.

If you're getting better quality by turning the resolution up, then there's going to eventually be some threshold where your project fits your resolution requirements.

EDIT: Upon close inspection, your image viewer looks like it's viewing it at 800% - pixelation should be expected at this magnification level.

I would recommend move the camera closer to the object (Likely by changing your Z-axis height closer to the origin) to capture only on the elements you need to be in high resolution.